# How to access JavaScript files in the assets folder in the angular-cli scripts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). I'm getting a 404 error for `scripts.bundle.js` file.

This might be with the file, which I've added in the scripts of `angular-cli` as below. How to access the JavaScript files, which are there in the assets folder in the angular-cli scripts.

```
"apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "index": "index.html",
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "assets/js/slick.min.js",
        "assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "assets/js/jquery.placeholder.min.js",
        "assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
        "assets/js/plugins.js",
        "assets/js/popper.min.js"
    ],
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
    "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
}],
```

Comment: your root is src so if the assets directory is inside src whatever your doing is correct, if your assets directory is outside just make sure to add ../assets/

Comment: assets are inside root only but still i am facing issue. i ma not getting those js related functionality into application

Comment: Check maybe the order of the scripts. I see jquery is almost last, maybe it loads them in order, so the plugins fail to load. Do you get any errors in the browser Console when you load the page ?